# Use Javascript scripts libraries to build React components using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to use a script library to build a React component and I don't know how to import this file properly. In my case [this](https://github.com/kekscom/L.Line3) one. I've seen other similar questions, but answers weren't enough specific. Webpack will be probably helpful for that, I've read about `externals` but that wasn't enough for me to make it fully working.

I've tried importing the script in my `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kekscom/L.Line3/master/dist/L.Line3.js"></script>
</head>
```

And then making an `external` in `webpack.config`:

```
externals: {
  line3: "Line3"
}
```

Also tried `line3`, `L.Line3`. When I try to `require('line3')` it returns me `undefined`.

Comment: I've added a code snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I have deleted my previous comments to keep your question clean.

Comment: Are you sure that the file from rawgit works?

Comment: There is an example in the github repo of this module working and this rawgit link provides a file so I thought it was ok. I can use a local file if it's a better approach.